# amcharts: trying to dynamically add multiple datasets to javascript stockChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, amcharts

I am using AmCharts for displaying some charts and I am trying to dynamically add the data from a series of JSON data sets which are acquired using jquery's `getJSON`

My question in short is, how do I loop through my various data sets creating dataSets for the charts using something like:

```
$.getJSON("GET NUMBER OF DATA SETS REQUIRED", function (locdata) {

 $.each(locdata, function (i, item) {

     $.getJSON("GET DATA FOR THIS DATASET", function (data) {

         var dataSet = new AmCharts.DataSet();
         dataSet.title = locdata[i].name;
         dataSet.fieldMappings = [{
             fromField: "takings",
             toField: "takings"
         }, {
             fromField: "qty",
              toField: "qty"
         }];
         dataSet.dataProvider = data; ;
         dataSet.categoryField = "date";

         )};
    )};
)};
```

To explain what I am doing here:

1. Firstly, getting some JSON output from my database to determine how many record sets are required
2. Looping through the result from this to create recordsets
3. During each loop, the data is acquired by a second jQuery `getJSON` call to grab data based on the data required for this recordset
4. Creating an AmCharts Dataset

I can manually do this by explicitly coding to create each dataset individually and then doing

```
 chart.dataSets = [dataSet0, dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3, dataSet4];
```

So I guess what I need to do is turn the whole of the code above into some kind of function which generates an array of datasets as per the line above?

I'm not sure how to do this with javascript though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply push each data set to chart.dataSets array:

chart.dataSets.push(dataSet);

Comment: That looks nice and easy, but I can't get it to work. I'm getting a blank chart as if it's rendering the chart too soon, ie, before the JSON data has been grabbed from my database and turned into amCharts dataSets

Comment: The `push` DOES work, but only if I chuck something in to slow down rendering. So, I'm looping all my data sets as per my Question, I've put a count into the `$.each` loop so I can determine when `$.each` has finished, then I have an `if` statement triggered when everything's looped properly, next a separate function (makeChart) which generates and renders the chart. If I finish up my `getData` function with 
                `alert("Chart Ready");
                makeChart(chart); `    it will work if I wait a while before pressing OK on the alert. Without the alert I just get a blank grid!

Comment: So, to summarize, I need some kind of listener to determine when the datasets are all ready... any ideas?!

Comment: Fixed it! Took a bit of fiddling, but it's all sorted now, thanks!